# Advanced Catalog Search showing wrong catalog

Tags: setup, advanced-search, dashboard

I'm new to Magento and am working on my new company's previously existing site.  I've managed to iron out most of the kinds except for one:

We have one account running the back-end of two websites with two very different product groups.  The site I am working on now has no issues with its actual catalog, but when I go to the "Advanced Search" page it only displays options for the *other* website's catalog.

I'm sure this is a quick fix, but I'm operating via the dashboard and cannot find any way to manipulate the Advanced Search.

Thank-you in advance!

Comment: Did you ever fix this?